# Difference between the sample quantiles

Tags: probability, quantiles

Say I have two pairs of random variables, $X_1,...X_n$ and $Y_1,...Y_n$, both continuous. With probability 1, the distance $|X_i-Y_i|\leq \eta_{n}$ for all $i$, and the distance converges to 0. I am curious if the sample quantiles still have some correspondence, i.e. if $X_{1}$ is the smallest value among all $X$s, would $Y_{1}$ be the smallest among all $Y$s with prob 1?

My intuition told me this was correct, but I'm unsure how to write a valid proof.

Answer (score 0):

It depends *how fast* $\eta_n\to 0$.  Consider $X$ and $Y$ both uniform on $[0,1]$.  The typical distance between the smallest observation $Y_1$ and the second-smallest $Y_2$ is $1/n$, and the same for $X$s.  So, if $\eta_n$ is much smaller than $1/n$, you would expect $X_1$ to be much closer to $Y_1$ than to $Y_2$, and $X_2$ to be much closer to $Y_2$ than to $Y_1$. If $\eta_n$ is much larger than $1/n$, there would be a substantial chance that $X_1+\eta_n > X_2-\eta_n$, so the condition on $|X_i-Y_i|$ doesn't constraint $P(Y_1<Y_2)$ very strongly.

To argue that the *whole* ordering was likely to be the same you'd need to get bounds for the minimum gaps between adjacent $X$s and between adjacent $Ys. This would take some work, especially if you wanted a sharp bound, but it's the sort of result that someone has probably derived already.

Comment: Are you perhaps implicitly assuming the $X$ and $Y$ are *independent?*

Comment: I'm not assuming the $X$s are independent of the $Y$s. I am assuming the $(X_i,Y_i)$ pairs are independent of each other -- the claim certainly isn't true with unrestricted dependence.

Comment: The claim is still false.  Just consider a situation where all the $X_i$ are positive variables and so are the $Y_i$ *except* for $Y_2,$ which is a negative variable.  You can still arrange for $|X_2-Y_2|$ to become vanishingly small. Yet even when $X_1$ is the smallest of the $X_i,$ $Y_1$ cannot ever be the smallest of the $Y_i,$ regardless of what you might assume of $\eta_n.$